# build error: error building at STEP "RUN /usr/libexec/s2i/assemble"

Tags: openshift

I have faced this error with OpenShift:

```
error: build error: error building at STEP "RUN /usr/libexec/s2i/assemble": error while running runtime: exit status 1
```

This is the log:

```
Using SDK: 3.1.111
---> Restoring application dependencies...
  Restore completed in 4.45 sec for /opt/app-root/src/PMCModel/PMCModel.csproj.
  Restore completed in 13.92 sec for /opt/app-root/src/PMCBackEnd/PMCBackEnd.csproj.
---> Publishing application...
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.111/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1175,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/opt/app-root/src/SharedModule/SharedModule.csproj]
/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.111/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1175,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/opt/app-root/src/PMCModel/PMCModel.csproj]
error: build error: error building at STEP "RUN /usr/libexec/s2i/assemble": error while running runtime: exit status 1
```

Comment: I use Linux Docker, I found that I have 2 Library in .net framework 4.8, So I changed to .net standard 2.0, using free OpenShift is not given me some clarification about the raised issue, so I stop using it.